# Using Text Encoding in C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli

I am using:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx#Y2160

to connect and get information from a server. This is my code:

```
// Connect to the server
TcpClient^ client = gcnew TcpClient( "1.1.1.1", 45257 );

// Get stream
NetworkStream^ stream = client->GetStream();

// Data to send
array<Byte>^data = Text::Encoding::ASCII->GetBytes( message );

// Send data to server
stream->Write( data, 0, data->Length );
```

However, I am getting these errors:

```
error C3083: 'Encoding': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type
error C2039: 'ASCII' : is not a member of 'System::Windows::Forms::Form::Text'
error C2065: 'ASCII' : undeclared identifier
error C2227: left of '->GetBytes' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

This is inside of a windows form application.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: As an aside, why are you using `System::Net::Sockets` from C++, which has direct access to the Winsock API, which is much more powerful, more efficient, and in many ways also more friendly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either specify the name space in a using directive, `using namespace System::Text;`, or specify the class name with full namespace, `System::Text::Encoding`.